# Is there a way to determine the type of an attribute in an AWS DynamoDB item with Node.js?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Each item in my table represents a social media post. 
It has the following definition:

{
   "title": string,
   "user_id": string,
   "description: string,
   "likes": set,
   "comments": list
}

When I'm updating an item, I want to overwrite the existing value if it's a string and add to the existing value if it's a set/list. How do I determine the type of an attribute? Is this the best way to design my table?

Comment: Afik you can't append to a string, you can always do a get then an update.

Comment: Btw, I would put likes and comments in separate tables, one record per comment/like as item size is limited to 400k and may exceed easely by adding multiple comments to a post